# Why can I not set the selection of a drop down list in VB.net before the form has been shown?

Tags: vb.net, dropdownbox

I cannot seem to get Visual Studio 2010 to let me set the SelectedItem or SelectedIndex property of a drop down list before the form has been shown on the screen. I can set these without issue if I wait until the form can be seen, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Here is my code.

```
Private Sub Test_Program_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For each item in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + "\Pictures\")
        dd_pics.items.add(item)
    Next
    dd_pics.SelectedIndex = 0
    background = dd_pics.SelectedIndex
End Sub
```

background is an integer variable. I've tried to change SelectedIndex to SelectedItem and change the background variable type to string, but that hasn't helped. Later in the code, I use the background variable to set a picture based on the file it references from the above code. I do not get an error, but it seems as if Visual Studio is skipping the line `dd_pics.SelectedIndex = 0` and all sequential lines in the Sub. I found this out because I'm actually getting an error when I try to set the picture referenced here to a PictureBox and the debugger is telling me there is Nothing in the variable I am trying to set the PictureBox to. I can use the exact same code in a button and it works fine. The only difference I can find is that the form is fully loaded and I have to click the button where it is automated here. Can anybody at least tell me when Visual Studio is having this problem or possibly how to fix it? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try changing the `SelectedIndex` value in one of these two events instead: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated(v=vs.110).aspx  or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Visual Vincent - Unfortunately, those didn't help. Nothing changed when I added the `Me.Activate()` line. I tried it at the beginning of the Form and right before the `dd_pics.SelectedIndex = 0` line. I also tried calling the Sub that is giving me problems from the `Me.Shown` sub, but that didn't change anything, either. I did find some new information. Rather than skipping the remaining lines, it is now repeating the function that the `dd_pics` line is in. Not sure why, but if I comment out the `dd_pics` line it keeps running.

Comment: what is `dd_pics`, a CBO?  That is not the real code, so you might set a breakpoint and watch what happens.  If an exception is thrown in FormLoad or Sub New, they are not reported.  Maybe set it to AnyCpu and run it to see

Comment: @Plutonix - `dd_pics` is a Combo Box. I forget they are not called drop down menus. I will try setting a break point when I get home and see what happens. What am I setting to AnyCpu and how do I do that? I'm haven't heard of AnyCpu before.

Comment: It's difficult to help you troubleshoot this as we're not able to see the full scope of the problem. Would you edit your question to include the entire affected code.

Comment: You might show any form level declarations.  you almost certainly have a silent exception going on.  Be sure Option Strict is on also

Comment: Most likely you have an exception that is getting swallowed by the Load() event.  Move that code to the **Shown()** event and see what happens.

Comment: @Plutonix - I've never used breakpoints before so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but it won't let me add a breakpoint except at the line where the function is called. Unfortunately this didn't help. I also turned Option Strict On, and the corrected several errors. Nothing came up as an error relating to the aforementioned problems, and also, the problem continues. I'm still not getting and error. It just loops that one Sub. No clue what's going on...

Comment: you should be able to set one on the `For each` shown.  IF you have any form level declarations, edit your post to show them.  We have much less to go on than you at this point

Comment: I was able to set the breakpoint. It let me check the contents of `dd_pics.SelectedItem` and `dd_pics.SelectedIndex`. The breakpoint had to be before the line that set the `dd_pics` variable. When the breakpoint came at first, I wasn't surprised that these were not set properly. The index was -1 and the item was empty. I let it continue and when it looped and came to the breakpoint again, they contents were the same. It is ignoring the line that sets the index and going back to the top of the Sub. I also added a `MsgBox` before and after that line. Only the before box pops up.

Comment: I don't think I have any form level declarations. If you mean global variables, I have an integer that is set later in the program to the total number of files in the Pictures folder and a Bitmap that I leave empty until later that I use to set the selected picture as the background. That is where I first got an error. I didn't have the drop down index set to anything and I made a call to this bitmap incorrectly. I got the problem I have now when trying to set the index of the drop down.

Comment: `the line that set the dd_pics variable` ??? I thought it was a CBO?   Also if the code is *really* in FOrmLoad then it should only be called once and once only.  There is just too much we dont know.

Comment: I'm sorry. Bad wording on my part. By `dd_pics` variable I meant `dd_pics.SelectedIndex`. Not a variable, but can be set like one. The code is only called once, but for whatever reason, it is stopping execution of the FormLoad event/Function/Sub/whatever when it hits that line, and restarting execution of the code from the top of the FormLoad event. Sorry for not being more precise.

Comment: well it will not let you set the SelectedIndex if nothing is in the CBO, which is what you want to debug.  Set the breakpoint at the start of the loop, when it stops, hold the mouse over each var and see if any is nothing. Then single step to see if it gets thru one iteration of the loop.  It sounds like the loop bombs, perhaps a path error.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that's the case. I've verified the path. The `For each` loop adds each file in the folder to the array of `dd_pics.items`. I set the breakpoint and check like you said but each time it adds another item to the array until it exits the loop. I can't verify the last item, but I did for all the others. I'm trying to set it to the first item, so the last item shouldn't matter since there are five files in the folder. Hope this helps. I have to go for tonight, other duties to attend to but I'll check back tomorrow. Thanks to everyone for all the help.

Comment: Re: `dd_pics.SelectedIndex`...  those are called Properties. You would refer to it as "the CBO's `SelectedIndex` property." A form-level (or, more accurately, a class-level) declaration is called a Field. `Class Test _ Private SomeField As String _ End Class` (`_` means line break here)

Comment: Alright here comes the crazy. I think the code file or the solution or something got corrupted and caused this. I went to open the project earlier today to get a message that Visual Studio could not open the project. I was unable to get any of the files in the project to open in Visual Studio. I opened the code files in Notepad, thinking they should look like plain text, but all I got was a bunch of gibberish. So I created a new project and started with this aspect and it worked. I'm guessing it was partially corrupt yesterday and caused this, and fully corrupted overnight. Crazy, right?

Answer (score 0):

I usually do these in the constructor:

```
Public Sub New()

  ' This call is required by the designer.
  InitializeComponent()

  ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
  For each item in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + "\Pictures\")
    dd_pics.items.add(item)
  Next
  dd_pics.SelectedIndex = 0
  background = dd_pics.SelectedIndex
End Sub
```

Could this work in your situation?

Comment: I've actually never used a constructor in VB before. I've always let Visual Studio handle it. Where should I put this?

Comment: You can include a constructor method anywhere in your class. To tell Visual Studio to enter it for you, left-click to select the class name and then select New in the Navigation Bar's Method Name drop-down list. Nevertheless, you may safely ignore my answer. Your problem is somewhere else; if it's failing in Form_Load it'll fail in the constructor as well. You really should edit your question to include the entire class, so we can see what's going on. You're asking us to fly blind otherwise.